# same-line iteration through list/string in if statement

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, iteration

In python 3.

```
a = True
b = 'ab'
letters = 'abcd'
if a and (b[0] in letters or b[1] in letters):
     do sth
```

Is there a more efficient way to iterate through the string if there are more than 2 elements in b (e.g. b = '5b$"£$$-')?

Thank you

Comment: What language? Please edit your question and add a tag for the right one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possibility:

```
if any(x in letters for x in b):
   do whatever
```

Comment: The expresion `(b[0] in letters or b[1] in letters)` is equivalent to `any` not to `all`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
a = True
b = "..."
letters = "..."

if a and 1 in [1 for i in b if i in letters]:
    do ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The possible simple ways I can think of are:

1 - Using [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html?highlight=set#module-sets):

```
>>> a = True
>>> b = 'ab'
>>> letters = 'abcd'
>>> common = set(b).intersection(set(letters))
>>> if a and common:
    print 'There are letters common letters between b and letters'
```

2 - Using built-in method [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=any#any) :

```
>>> if a and any(i in letters for i in b):
    print 'There are letters common letters between b and letters'
```